# Label.text is nil

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to show `userNameLabel` with content "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA" but `userNameLabel` is `nil`.

```
class ChooseMemberTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Reusable {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    func setupCell(data: User) {
        userNameLabel?.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA"
//        userNameLabel?.text = "\(data.userName)"
//        let url = URL(string: data.image)
//        userImageView.sd_setImage(with: url ?? "", completed: nil)
    }
}
```

Additional code from comment:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = listContacts.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: ChooseMemberTableViewCell.self).then { 
        let user = searchUser[indexPath.row] 
        $0.setupCell(data: user) 
    } 
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is nil? Does the label not exist, or is the text not showing?

Comment: the label is nil most likely. you did not connect it in the xib

Comment: I mean the text is not showing

Comment: Where are you calling setupCell?

Comment: i'm calling it in
```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = listContacts.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: ChooseMemberTableViewCell.self).then {
            let user = searchUser[indexPath.row]
            $0.setupCell(data: user)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: i debug with po userNameLabel?.text, which is nil

Comment: Make sure the IBOutlet for userNameLabel is connected

Comment: i'm sure about that.

Comment: userNameLabel is not optional , then why do you access it as userNameLabel?.text ? Also where do you call setupCell?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri userNameLabel is optional. It's just declared as implicitly unwrapped.

Besides that, is the userNameLabel nil? Or is it just the text?

Comment: If i remove '?', the problem still not be solved. I Call setupCell in cellForRowAt of TableView

Comment: your implementation of cellForRow is strange. Is   $0 points to unwrapped cell and listContacts points to the same reference of tableView ?

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri i'm using Reusable library.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. In my case problem was in cell registration method. I was using `register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` but this was not working because my cell was created in xib. Using `register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` helped me out.